# hasMany is not fetching records

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have created 3 Domain classes

```
 class Menu {
    String menuName
    static hasMany = [menuItems : MenuItem ]
    ...
}

class MenuItem {
    String itemName
    ...
    static belongsTo = [menu: Menu]
    static hasMany = [menuItemTaxes : MenuItemTax ]
}

class MenuItemTax {
    String taxName
    ...
    static belongsTo = [menuItem: MenuItem]
}
```

In Controller, When I tried this, It is printing null

```
MenuItem menuItem = MenuItem.findById(validId)
println(menuItem.menuItemTaxes)
```

But, I can see records in database, and when I print menuItem it is also getting printed. What went wrong. Is it because of nested hasMany relation?

Comment: "Is it because of nested hasMany relation?" - No.  You haven't shown enough context to know what is going wrong, but in general what you show there does work.  If you pointed to a sample app which demonstrated the behavior it would be trivial to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are correct.

Its possible that menuItem exits in your database and therefore, its printed but what could happen is that menuItemTaxes that belong to the corresponding may not exist in your database.

I would look into the menuitemtax table to see it there are valid entries whose menu_item_id is equal the "validId" you are passing in the following statement

```
MenuItem menuItem = MenuItem.findById(validId)
```